# Can I clean install Ubuntu over top of existing Ubuntu install partition on a Windows dual-boot drive without reformatting whole drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, hard-drive

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual-booted on my hard drive. My Ubuntu installation became kind of messed up and I don't know how to fix it. So it would just be easier for me to just do a fresh install of Ubuntu over the existing partition. Is there a way for me to do this without reformatting the whole drive and having to reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Just choose ["something else" during installation for manual partitioning](/q/343268/175814) and reformat the *partitions* that Ubuntu is supposed to use. Obviously, all their data will be lost in the process, but no need to touch Windows partitions.

*Relevant comment by [TrailRider](/users/65969/trailrider)*:

> The answer is correct but may have be more complicated that needed. You should be able to boot from the cd/usb and after clicking the install button, the choices window should give you the option to "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall" . Selecting that would format the Ubuntu partition only and do a clean install of Ubuntu.

Comment: The answer is correct but may have be more complicated that needed.  You should be able to boot from the cd/usb and after clicking the install button, the choices window should give you the option to "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall" .  Selecting that would format the Ubuntu partition only and do a clean install of Ubuntu.  I will upvote as your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @TrailRider: I think you should mention this in a separate answer. I like yours better and will upvote it, if you do.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is a duplicate and will be closed as such.  The duplicate does not mention upgrading specifically so the question might help some else.  As your answer was already accepted and is perfectly correct, I will just leave it as a comment for more info.  Alternately, if you wish, you are free to edit your answer to include the info from my comment.